# Facebook php SDK login sometimes fails

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-login

I have problems with the facebook login. I have my php start page with the login link:

```
$facebook = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($redirect_url);
$permissions = array('email');
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($permissions);
```

And then I have my redirect page with this code:

```
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( $redirect_url);

try 
{
    $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
}
catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) 
{
    // When Facebook returns an error
}
catch( Exception $ex ) 
{
    // When validation fails or other local issues
}


// see if we have a session
if ( isset( $session ) ) 
{
   // I'm logged in
}
else
{
  // got no session
}
```

For about 10% of my users they don't get a $session. All others can login without problems but not these 10%. Why not?`Is there any way to find out why?

Answer (score -1):

To my knowledge the SDK has been updated, i'm using this now and it's working fine: [FB SDK Login - Php](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login)

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I updated to the new SDK but I still have about 20% of the user who can't login. With the new SDK I get the error message "Cross-site request forgery validation failed. The "state" param from the URL and session do not match" I checked the value of $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] but the url seems to be okay after I read that there is a different between mypage.com and www.mypage.com. I use
    if(!session_id()) {
        session_start();
    }
at the top of both scripts but I still get the error with some users.